# Why fgets(char* buffer, int size, stdin) don't cause Segmentation Fault all time whenever given input string large enough then size of char buffer[]

Tags: c, input, compiler-errors, inputstream, fgets

consider a typical C program :

```
   int main()
    {
        char buffer[5];                   
        fgets(buffer, 8, stdin);

        printf("%s", buffer);

        return 0;
    }
```

I have compiled this code in several machines and various compilers and came to the conclusion that some time compiler gives segmentation fault error and sometime not, but it supposed to give error because our **char buffer[5]** isn't large enough to hold string of length more than 5. But when I compile this in my machine with **input : 12345678** then I'm getting **output : 1234567** but I was expecting **error : SEGMENTATION FAULT**.

I am expecting explanation other than this, *Chat-Gpt : "However, the reason why you might not immediately encounter a segmentation fault or error is due to the nature of undefined behavior. Just because you're writing beyond the bounds of the array doesn't necessarily mean the program will crash immediately. The behavior could vary depending on the compiler, the operating system, and other factors."*
Consider the fact that if we initialize,
`char buffer[5] = "SAYAN";` and we want to
`print("%c", buffer[6]);` compiler immediately shows error : segmentation fault in this case.

Comment: FYI: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). ChatGPT already tells you the problem. Undefined Behavior (UB). Everything can happen when you run your code. The standard does not require any predictable results.

Comment: I hate to say so but ChatGPT is right in that case. _Undefined Behaviour_ means _anything_ can happen including that everything seems to work fine. Also you're wrong with Your assumption that in your `printf()` example "compiler immediately shows error ". Besides the fact that a segfault happend on run time and not in the compiler a bug like this also could seem to work fine just like you've experienced with `fgets()`

Comment: Because it didn't. I ran a red light but I didn't get squashed. There is no automatic squashing or traffic violation. But the following day, I ran the red light and got squashed.

Comment: What kind of answer were you expecting besides the one given by ChatGPT?

Comment: "but it supposed to give error" -- This statement is incorrect. If your program violates the rules of the language, thereby invoking undefined behavior, then anything may happen, which includes the possibility of a segmentation fault, but also includes the possibility of your program behaving as intended, or something completely different happening. You cannot rely on any specific behavior when invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: If you want your program to more reliably detect out of bounds memory access, then you may want to run your program with [AddressSanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_sanitizer) (which is included by default in the gcc and clang compilers, and is also available for MSVC). That tool is able to detect your out of bounds access, as you can see in [this demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/cxzqKfbzP).